# Why echo in php always leads to "1 problem in this file"

Tags: php, html

I am having huge problems with using echo in PHP. I thought that it is my mistake, so I went to w3schools to copy a simple line and paste it, but I still got "1 problem in this file"

The line I am trying is like that

```
        <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION["userid"])){
          
          echo "<p> Здравей, " . $_SESSION["userid"] ."</p>";
        ?>
```

I have also tried that line from w3schools which also seems to not be working

```
        <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION["userid"])){
          
          echo 'One line simple string.<br />';
        ?>
```

And basically every other I try is not working as well.

Comment: you are missing closing bracket of if.

Comment: did w3schools mention that you have to start the session before using any session variables?

Comment: @aviboy2006 Thank you so much, can't believe I didn't see something so simple. God bless.

Comment: Tip:While working on a big project, make a header.php file where you start the session so next time onwards you will not have to think about starting one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using session you have to start first session. Also you were missing closing `if` bracket.

```php
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["userid"] = "testuser";
        if(isset($_SESSION["userid"])){
          
          echo "<p> Здравей, " . $_SESSION["userid"] ."</p>";
       }
        ?>
```